# SSIS export data to database with similar scheme on different server

Tags: ssis

I have to similar databases on different instances. 
I needed to export All data in All tables from One instance to another.

The problem i am having is i need to keep all the Unique Id's from the columns that i have the identity insert on. 
Example:

Value of (Instance1-->Table1-->Id(Identity Column))  needs to be the same as:
Value of (Instance2-->Table1-->Id(Identity Column)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your OLEDB destination, there is an option called `KeepIdentity` Select this option. This is the equilavent of `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON`

Comment: Ok, Thanks. Is there a way i can do the entire database i.e All tables? Or do i have to do it one by one?